# Difference between "2-year community or junior colleges" and "4 year undergraduate program" in USA

Tags: masters, united-states, education, bachelor, community-college

I am confused about the USA education system.

I looked up the [Wikipedia page about K-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9312). In particular, the figure on the right of that page.

Let's supposed I have just finished high school and I want a MSc in Computer Science.

1. It's pretty clear from the figure that I can apply to a MSc after a "4-year undergraduate program". My question here is: would this program award me a BSc?
2. It is unclear to me how the other path, the "2-year community or junior college" would work out. My questions here are:

   a. What kind of title would a "2-year community or junior college" would award me? A BSc?

   b. Can I apply for a MSc after a "2-year community or junior college"?

   c. As I interpret the figure, I think that, after a "2-year community or junior college", I would still have to obtain a "4-year undergraduate program" before applying for a "Master's degree study". Here is my big question here: if that is the case, why I should apply to a "2-year community or junior college", and having to pursue a "4-year undergraduate program" nonetheless, instead of applying directly to a "4-year undergraduate program" after high school? Stated otherwise, why should a person enroll in a "2-year community or junior college" and then pursue a "4-year undergraduate program", instead of pursuing the "4-year undergraduate program" directly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two-year degrees in the US often award either an "associates degree" or some technical certification/profession-specific degree.

These degrees are *not* typically part of the "bachelors -> masters -> PhD" pipeline or more generic "bachelors -> professional degree".

Some students may start taking courses at a 2-year school and then *transfer* to a 4-year school (with or without actually completing a 2-year degree, and hoping to have as many of their 2-year credits count/transfer towards their 4-year degree), because 2-year schools are both less expensive and less selective. 2-year programs rarely have any sort of on-site housing ("dorms") and limited "student life" opportunities (clubs, social facilities, athletics).

Not all 2-year schools are appropriate for this track. Some are specifically designed as technical degrees to get students into a specific career, and do not provide the "general education" credits (basic math, science, social studies courses) that are useful for transferring to a 4-year program.

---

If you wanted a MSc in the US, starting from high school you would either:

A) Enroll at a 4-year program, and then

B) Apply to Masters programs*

or

A) Enroll in a 2-year program,

B) Transfer to a 4-year program (bringing with you some or all of the credits you already earned), and then

C) Apply to Masters programs*

If you plan for the "ABC" pipeline it is definitely worth exploring the requirements of the 4-year institution(s) you plan to attend so that you know which courses you take will transfer (some 4-year schools have explicit relationships with particular 2-year schools to define classes that will count for transfer credit). Most students who would follow this path instead of the "AB" path would be doing so either for financial reasons or because the student does not feel academically prepared for a 4-year school (the quality of high school education varies quite a bit in the US, and even a very good student at a disadvantaged high school might have trouble with the jump to a 4-year school).

There is no particular advantage to completing a 2-year degree program before starting a fresh 4-year degree - the only reason to start at a 2-year program if your goal is a MSc would be if you can transfer credits from the 2-year to 4-year program.

(* - it's possible, though not particularly common in the US, that you enroll directly for a combined bachelors+masters program)

Comment: Good answer, but "a very good student at a disadvantaged institution might have trouble with the jump to a 4-year school"  This is not true.  Often it is guaranteed that certain offerings of a community college are equivalent to the offerings of 4-year colleges.  This is called an "articulation agreement."  While certainly there is a difference between the weakest community colleges and the strongest 4-year colleges, in most cases if a student can succeed in community college but not in 4-year college, it is because the 4-year college is doing a *bad job*.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Not sure I get your meaning. Maybe I was unclear, as I was referring to the student's high school. Community colleges are likely to have better opportunities for bridge courses (which might be offered at a 4-year school, but at full tuition and likely do not count towards the degree), and more generally there is more attention paid to students in the "100-level" courses than they'd likely find in a 4-year school. "Equivalent" is...well...rarely truly so.

Comment: "more generally there is more attention paid to students in the "100-level" courses than they'd likely find in a 4-year school"  Exactly.  It's not that students are not prepared for the four year college; the four year college is not prepared for the students.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You can work towards making that change at the 4 year colleges from whatever position you have now. For a soon-to-be-undergraduate student, it doesn't matter who is at fault, they need to join the program that fits them, not show up to a 4 year college and complain the school isn't prepared for them when they are expected to do a lot more learning on their own and starting from a higher level expectation compared to what they saw in high school.

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, but: "For a soon-to-be-undergraduate student, it doesn't matter who is at fault"  It does matter.  The community college stigma, which is mostly myth, does real harm to students.  Most four year colleges in America are not actually selective.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I don't disagree with you as far as "community college stigma" but I don't see how I am advocating for cementing the stigma. If anything I'm suggesting it's a good route for many many people. Really your comments make little sense *in the context of this Q&A* about differences in 2 and 4 year institutions. Please take it someplace else if you want to argue that 4-year institutions should do more to serve certain students than they are doing now.

Comment: Following @gnometorule comment (and I have seen you explained this in the other parts), when you say "There is no particular advantage to completing a 2-year degree program before starting a fresh 4-year degree.". If you do that, you start the 4-year degree program "at year 3", right?

Comment: The vagueness of "disadvantaged high school might have trouble with the jump to a 4-year school" does perpetuate that stigma.  It would be better to say a student from a disadvantaged school might find a community college is more accustomed to the challenges that student faces.  You inadvertently implied that community college courses are lower level than the equivalent courses at four year colleges.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You're reading something not written here. Equivalent community college courses need not be "lower level" as you write, they only need to have expectations similar to what a student would face in an (urban/low income/majority minority) high school. That's not the same as "lower level". They also may include courses that a 4-year institution assumes people have completed in high school (a course name I have in mind is "college math" - oddly translated as "math you need before calculus"). 2-year schools have a course like this normally. 4-year schools consider it remedial.

Comment: That distinction doesn't say the 2-year school is *bad*. It says it is sometimes *better for someone whose high school didn't prepare them*.

Comment: @raffaem Yep, good point. I meant to say that there is no benefit to do (2 year degree) + (4 year degree) for later schooling. If your goal is a (4 year degree) and you start this by first transferring (2 year school credits) to your (4 year school) that's another matter. Do you think my edit helps clarify that or is there another place it is unclear? Thank you

Comment: "sometimes better for someone whose high school didn't prepare them."  Your answer should say that, instead of what it currently says.  It's a minor detail, but an improvement.

Comment: You can also finish a two year then apply for four year

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- You *can*, but there isn't much advantage to do so besides having the two-year to fall back on.

Comment: @BryanKrause Just for a completeness of information.

Comment: @raffaem: *If you do that, you start the 4-year degree program "at year 3", right?* --- It is a bit simplistic to think in terms of "year 1", "year 2", etc. because for the 4-year degree there are certain requirements (depending on subject major and the college/university) such as subject major courses (some of which are specifically required, others chosen from courses offered by the department) and required elective courses (e.g. several humanities, several social sciences, some math, maybe a foreign language, sometimes even physical education, etc.), **(continued)**

Comment: and additional elective courses (sometimes your subject major courses can satisfy this requirement, sometimes these have to be courses taken from other departments). Usually "3rd year" is based on how many credit hours you have obtained (i.e. courses taken), but it's not all that unusual for students *even in their 4th year* to take courses that they should have taken in their first year --- a university-wide mathematics requirement is often an example of this. And even if such a course was taken at the community college, a transfer student might not get the credit hours for it.

Comment: You say "There is no particular advantage to completing a 2-year degree program before starting a fresh 4-year degree." I very strongly disagree with this statement, particularly if the student is planning on continuing on at a state university (or the private equivalent).  Community colleges typically have much smaller class sizes (eg there are no 300 person precalculus lectures), and the focus of faculty is on instruction. Because of this, introductory academic courses (calculus, English composition, intro to physics, etc) tend (in my experience) to be *better* at community colleges. (con't)

Comment: Moreover, community college classes are *much* cheaper than classes at other institutions.  There are definitely students for whom the high school to university pipeline is appropriate, but my generic advice to a generic high school senior is "Go to community college for two years.  Then transfer to university."  I don't see any particular advantage in going straight to university (for most students---there are exceptions).

Comment: @XanderHenderson That's why I specifically wrote before starting a *fresh* 4 year degree. There is no reason to take 6 years to do an associate's + bachelor's. The rest of the answer clearly describes why a 2 year program can be a way to start towards a 4 year program with transfer credits. The second half of the sentence you quote, in fact.

Comment: One advantage to completing the two-year degree is you'd lock in those credits/classes. If you take a multi-year break in schooling, the classes won't age out.

Answer (score 9):

A community college or junior college in the US offers a program that is roughly equivalent to the first two year of a bachelor's program. The degree awarded on successful completion is normally called an Associates Degree. In most cases it omits the more specialized "upper division" courses that bachelor's degree students take in the last two years.

An associates degree would normally not be sufficient to gain access to a masters program. The student would need to complete a bachelors first.

The advantage, for many, of an associates degree is that the college might be closer to home and it might have a much lower tuition cost than a bachelors degree program. As implied in the name "community college", many of them are partially funded by community taxes. Some of these colleges are very good, actually. I know people at a few of them and have high respect for what they do. But they aren't involved in any kind of serious research for the most part.

Some community colleges also offer non-academic training in various trades such as plumbing and carpentry.

I should also note, that since times are difficult in academia at the moment, some quite highly skilled "academics" wind up teaching in community colleges. One can build a career there if you are willing to focus almost everything on teaching.

Comment: "they aren't involved in any kind of serious research for the most part."  To be clear, they do not do research because their mission is teaching.  For a community college, research is just not part of the goal.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, that is correct, but some are _incorrigible_ and do research on their own time and dime. But the mission is teaching and service.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist (and Buffy) That being said, there are some community colleges where faculty are still involved in research, and even a few CC -run research seminars.  Fullerton College in California, for example, has a mathematics seminar (or did a few years ago, at any rate).  This is the exception, but there are a few places out there. :)

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are largely correct. For those with higher-academia goals, community colleges provide Associates Degrees, and opportunities to apply those credits directly to a later 4-year degree. The primary reasons students attend these institutions are (a) lower annual cost than 4-year schools, and/or (b) students who cannot satisfy 4-year college admissions requirements, and hope to establish a track record that allows them to do so later.

That said, there are variations in institutions that the other answers don't cover. For example, I work at a community college in the CUNY (City University of New York) system, one of 25 campuses, including both 2-year and 4-year colleges, around the city. The three things I'd highlight at our schools are:

- While the 4-year schools have significant admissions requirements, the 2-year schools are [open admissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_admissions); any student with a high-school diploma or the equivalent is guaranteed placement.
- A student who earns an appropriate Associate's Degree at a 2-year school is then guaranteed placement at a 4-year school within the system, with all earned credits transferring over. So the 2-year degree serves as successful completion of the first 2 years of a 4-year degree. (Even if the student could not initially meet the admissions requirement of the 4-year school.)
- Faculty throughout the university system (2-year and 4-year) are all held to the same tenure requirements, including the need for published research. Admittedly, this is quite different from most other community colleges, where research is not a requirement.

In short, the 2-year school has historically provided an opportunity (maybe a "last chance") for a student to on-ramp to an academic path which will later take them to a Bachelor's, Master's, and perhaps Doctorate degree, and at a reduced cost for the first two years. That said: there are some rumors, in the current economic crisis, and based on perennially low success rates, that this on-ramp opportunity to higher education should be refocused to immediate workforce placement after the 2-year degree.

Comment: As something that fits with your answer, you might consider adding that in recent times another way a 2-year school has become an "on-ramp" is for foreign students who cannot demonstrate preparation for a 4 year school.  Some, if not many, 2-year schools have started sponsoring student visas for foreign students who (have money and) are committed to entering a 4-year school in the US but don't yet qualify because of language scores or other barriers.